# mate . command is not working in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, textmate

I am trying to open the content of a directory using text mate by **mate .** command.

But, I am getting the message :

```
-bash: mate: command not found
```

I tried the following command to fix it :

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate /usr/local/bin/mate
```

but, unfortunately this did not do the trick for me. It gives me the message :

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/mate: File exists
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Check what the existing `/usr/local/bin/mate` file is; and them `rm` it. You should be able to run your `ln -s` command afterward.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate /usr/local/bin/mate
```

worked for me after installing a MAC 10.9

Comment: This doesn't work with TextMate version 2 and macOS Hight Sierra

Comment: For newer versions, see user2299985's answer.

Answer (score 16):

For me TextMate shell command was not installed that is why i was getting this error.
To fix this, go to TextMate preferences, click on Terminal icon then click on 'install' shell command if it's not already installed (if it's already installed you will get option to 'uninstall').

Answer (score 10):

You can install the shell support in TextMate menu by the following steps:

**Textmate -> Preference -> Terminal -> Install**

[image]

Comment: this works for me!

Answer (score 4):

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /usr/local/bin/mate
```

works for mate 2.10

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is on your `$PATH`.